# How do I change the way VScode breaks lines in HTML and CSS?

Tags: html, visual-studio-code, monaco-editor

As you can see, this is not exactly the best way to break a line for a CSS selector
[image: VScode CSS line break issue]

It is showing the next selector's . on the same line that it is about to break 1 character later. Please advise me how to change line break detection method, and any language specific things I can do for CSS and HTML tags to not get cut off before their final, or second to final etc, character.

I have tried setting a very complex margin on the ime editor space drawn by the monaco editor but this causes rendering issues in many different instances. Any help appreciated

Margin and padding bounding - causes other errors
VScodes settings for where to break lines and how far to break lines in - nothing specific to this question
Extensions don't help either

Comment: is this word wrap or the formatter

Comment: is this your preferred theme, it could be called lowContrast

Comment: Please show the line numbers as well so we can see if you mean the code formatting (affects the code) or the word wrap display (it's only a visual in the editor). Can you post settings and related extensions? Does this happen with a VSCode without extensions? You can post an issue at the [VSCode issue tracker](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues) if you found a bug.

Comment: @Peter I cant post a picture in this comment reply but the line numbers are regular with no empty lines, but as you can see in the original post that the . of the next selector is on the same line that then breaks 1 character later. No extensions enabled. Thanks

Comment: @Rio It is vscode word wrap. No formatting Thanks

Comment: @starball This is not related it does not effect wrapping for me or line breaks.

Comment: @Cast you're right. apologies! I'm surprised though there's no value of the `editor.wrappingStrategy` setting that makes VS Code obey word separators for wrapping.

Comment: @starball Actually I didnt know about that settings and I just tried it now, it now wraps at the nearest classname. I would rather it wrapped at/before the next selector but this is still very good thanks. Do you know anyway to margin the editor's text so it doesn't get too close to the edge of the right of the screen? If I set a bounding width or column width it will be static on that specfic value Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following in settings.json:

```json
"[css]": {
    "editor.wrappingStrategy": "advanced",
    // "editor.wordWrapColumn": 80,  // uncomment to wrap at minimum of 80 characters / or screen width
    // "editor.wordWrap": "bounded", // uncomment to wrap at minimum of 80 characters / or screen width
},
```

I'm not sure why exactly this works, because the `"advanced"` value's description text isn't very... descriptive. But it seems to do the job. Personally, I'd have expected a wrapping strategy that respects the `editor.wordSeparators` setting, but that doesn't seem to be an option right now.

Comment: The problem with setting a column width is that it will always be that exact value. The text will never go beyond that value even when it can. I feel this is shotgun approach to just simply having a tiny bit of margin on the right of renderd lines. I am investigating javascript functions in the main workbench.js file that draws each "view-line" to try and dynamically add margin

Comment: @Cast your question post isn't about right padding anyway. the fact that I gave information about it since you mentioned it in the comments is just a bonus.

Comment: what? @starball